# What's the meaning of の at the end of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, nuances, particle-の

I came across this sentence while reading a Manga, so here are my questions.

> 本当に詳しい**の**ね

1. Is this の here is the female speech？
2. Is のね the same as んですね？

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, 「詳しいのね」has the same meaning of 「詳しいんだね」or 「詳しいんですね」. The「の」here signifies a kind, caring female. Mothers and protective figures (female) also usually speak like this.
2. Yes, 「んですね」is more formal, however.